# How to Implement log4net in ASP.NET MVC4 &Entity Framework 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I've used this example:
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

in data service controller:

readonly log4net.ILog _log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

To build the database,I'm using The database migration 
My project is based on durandal & breeze
My problem is that
 this code will not be added to the database log table, and I do not know where and how do I   use the variable _log and where is The database table definition

Where should we define the database table definition

Comment: try this https://dotnetdarren.wordpress.com/2010/07/29/logging-in-mvc-part-4-log4net/